# Power Apps People Picker Images

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am new power apps, by the way it is awesome. I just created a lovely tabbed form that also has conditional fields. And I am trying to add a customer people picker. The images don't come in so I found this code that recommended to look for an image or use another image instead. When I use the code I get an error stating the if function has invalid arguments.

```
With({
   personImage: Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(ThisItem.Mail),
   hasphoto: Office365Users.UserPhotoMetadata(ThisItem.UserPrincipalName).HasPhoto 
    },
    If (
    hasphoto,
    personImage,
    user
)
)
```

Comment: Where are you adding this formula, on which property and what type of control you used?

Comment: I had inserted a vertical gallery. The text results are coming from 365 user. I clicked on the sample image and the in fx for image I put the code from above. If I remove user it will work but displays nothing for users who don't have a photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula in "Image" property of image control:

```
If (
    Office365Users.UserPhotoMetadata(ThisItem.UserPrincipalName).HasPhoto,
    Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(ThisItem.Mail),
    User().Image
)
```

**OR**:

```
With(
    {
        personImage: Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(ThisItem.Mail),
        hasphoto: Office365Users.UserPhotoMetadata(ThisItem.UserPrincipalName).HasPhoto 
    },
    If (
        hasphoto,
        personImage,
        User().Image
    )
)
```